# How to use Super key alone to switch layouts and use Super key in shortcuts in Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I used to switch layouts by Super key and also used Super key in shortcuts in Ubuntu 16. Now I use Ubuntu 18 and can't get the same result.

Comment: "Super key in shortcut" you mean.. for layout switching super key and also you want combination of super keys to make other shortcuts. is my understanding correct?

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, exactly

Comment: 0k..so you are aware that you will loose original functionality of Super key if you intend to do so.. if you can loose the original behaviour of Super key it is possible.. I mean by physical look.. it is Super key but the function will be different..

Answer (score 0):

The way the super key behaves in Ubuntu 18.04, and in Gnome Shell, should not prevent you from defining your own hotkey combinations that involve <kbd>Super</kbd> as amodifier key. In fact, several hotkey combination involving <kbd>Super</kbd> are already defined by default. Nothing prevents you from adding your own.

This is because <kbd>Super</kbd> will trigger the Overview only once released. If you press the key, then press another key, a keyborad combination will be send, that you can assign to your custom script using Settings - Keyboard.

That said, you can disable the special action of the <kbd>Super</kbd> key alone with gsettings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''
```

You still can open the overview using the build in hotkey <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> or with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

If you wish to use <kbd>Super</kbd> on its own but for another function than showing the dash, you need to resort to [a utility `ksuperkey`](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey). That utility allows you to redirect pressing and releasing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to any other hotkey, which then can be assigned your custom function. Use of that utility requires disabling its normal function with the `gsettings` command shown above.